# Call requires permission which may be rejected by user code should explicitly check to see if permission is available

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, android-permissions

I add bluetooth to my app but am running into the following problem. When I do the code:

```
mDiscoverBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
if(!mBlueAdapter.isDiscovering()){
showToast("Making your device Discoverable");
Intent intent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
mDiscoverBtLauncher.launch(intent);
}
}
});

        mOffBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(mBlueAdapter.isEnabled()){
                    mBlueAdapter.disable();
                    showToast("Turning Bluetooth off");
                    mBlueTv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_off);
                }
                else{
                    showToast("Bluetooth is already off");
                }
            }
        });
```

The error is on the following line:

`mBlueAdapter.isDiscovering()`

`mBlueAdapter.disable();`

Error:

> Call requires permission which may be rejected by user: code should explicitly check to see if permission is available (with `checkPermission`) or explicitly handle a potential `SecurityException`

This is my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Bluetooth"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

and this is the permisstions I added to manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

I don't know how to solve this problem.

I need your help.

I added permission to manifest.
But the problem was left.

Comment: You have to check if you have the permission (call to checkSelfPermission) and if you do not have the permission: request it. See https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting#java for details about permissions and their handling / process.